# Flutter Cubit state does not leave the starting point (MyInitialState)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, bloc, state-management

I'm learning cubit / bloc but when I have a page that loads information from a json file, my status doesn't change.

I have no idea what is happening because it does not return any error, but through a print I can follow the current states.
I also did not find a source of information that uses this way, without the need for a click or something

**my cubit**

```
   class AgentesCubit extends Cubit<AgentesState> {
      final AgentesRepository _agentesRepository = JsonAgentesRepository();
      AgentesCubit() : super(AgentesInitial());
      List<Agentes> listAgentes;
    
      getAgentes() async {
        try {
          emit(AgentesLoading());
          _agentesRepository.loadAgentes().then((data) => listAgentes = data);
          print(listAgentes);
          emit(AgentesLoaded(listAgentes));
        } on NetworkError {
          emit(AgentesError('Ocorreu algo inesperado, tente novamente mais tarde'));
        }
      }
    }
    
    class NetworkError {}
```

**my states**

```
part of 'agentes_cubit.dart';

@immutable
abstract class AgentesState {
  const AgentesState();
}

class AgentesInitial extends AgentesState {
  const AgentesInitial();
}

class AgentesLoading extends AgentesState {
  const AgentesLoading();
}

class AgentesLoaded extends AgentesState {
  final List<Agentes> agentes;
  const AgentesLoaded(this.agentes);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object o) {
    if (identical(this, o)) return true;
    return o is AgentesLoaded && o.agentes == agentes;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => agentes.hashCode;
}

class AgentesError extends AgentesState {
  final String message;
  const AgentesError(this.message);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object o) {
    if (identical(this, o)) return true;

    return o is AgentesError && o.message == message;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => message.hashCode;
}
```

**my page**

```
class AgentesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: BlocBuilder<AgentesCubit, AgentesState>(
        cubit: AgentesCubit(),
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AgentesInitial) {
            print('initial');
            return buildLoading();
          } else if (state is AgentesLoading) {
            print('loading');
            return buildLoading();
          } else if (state is AgentesLoaded) {
            print('loaded');
            return buildAgentesList(state.agentes, context);
          }
          return Container();
        },
      )),
    );
  }

  buildLoading() {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }

  buildAgentesList(agentes, context) {
    print(agentes);
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: agentes.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => CustomAgenteItem(agentes[index])),
    );
  }

  void loadAgentes(BuildContext context) {
    final agentesCubit = context.bloc<AgentesCubit>();
    agentesCubit.getAgentes();
  }
}
```

**my agentes item widget**

```
class CustomAgenteItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Agentes agente;
  CustomAgenteItem(this.agente);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        highlightColor: mainColor,
        splashColor: mainColor,
        onTap: () => print(''),
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: new ParallaxImage(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, left: 16),
              child: Text(
                agente.nome,
                style: listAgents,
              ),
            ),
            extent: 100.0,
            image: new AssetImage(
              'assets/images/bg.jpg',
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

**my repository**

```
class AgentesRepository {
  loadAgentes() async {
    return agentesFromJson(
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/infos/agentes.json'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Long shot, I can see you are not awaiting for the api call in MyCUBIT. That can cause the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to `await` the result of `_agentesRepository.loadAgentes()` since it is an asynchronous function, otherwise the code block will continue to run the next line of code. You could also move all the code after that line into the function you pass to `.then` but it won't read as well.

Also it doesn't look like you need `listAgentes` defined on the `AgentesCubit` class

```
...
var data = await _agentesRepository.loadAgentes();
emit(AgentesLoaded(data));
...
```